# Deployment and Release process for R code

Tags: r, r.net

Recently we have started working for predictive modelling using R language;  our model is stable now but need to productionize it such using solid deployment, versioning and build process.

Anyone can provide insight into it ? As in C# we have proper build server, versioning, deployment tools etc; do we have somewhat similar suite in R

Comment: Not an expert, but could you use Docker?

Comment: You'd likely get better responses on the rOpenSci forum or Twitter. This q is very likely going to get closed soon.